# LibGdx Accelerometer max readings too low [-10, 10]

Tags: android, iphone, libgdx, max, accelerometer

LibGdx states that max readings for Accelerometer is only between [-10, 10]. However this is so low, it is completely unusable for anything other than a tilt game, since tilting without doing anything gives about 10 right away. Furthermore my S4 Galaxy readings go up to 19 so then I wonder -Is it hardware dependent and the least that can be guaranteed is just +/-10? What is the max for most Iphones vs most Androids?

Comment: It is, as I realized though, possible to calculate the derivate of the acc values by using delta variable between renders. This can sometimes be used to indicate that the phone is moving. Although if a reading is "saturated" the derivate will also be 0, so not perfect...